# Highcharts drilldown resize yAxis on drilldown/drillup

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I resize the yAxis on drilldown/drillup?

I have a drilldown column chart that could have series data from 100k+ to 1. Some categories in the drilldown are tiny compared to the yAxis extreme and are hard to make out the data label.

```
$("#chart").highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  yAxis: {
    minTickInterval: 100,
    max: 1000
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [
             {drilldown:1,"name":"Apples","y":203},
             {drilldown:2,"name":"Bananas","y":599},
             {drilldown:3,"name":"Oranges","y":427}
            ]
    }
  ],
    drilldown: {
        series: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "Apples",
            data: [["Foo", 58], ["Bar", 100], ["Baz", 45]]
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "Apples",
            data: [["Foo", 58], ["Bar", 100], ["Baz", 45]]
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: "Apples",
            data: [["Foo", 58], ["Bar", 100], ["Baz", 45]]
          }
        ]
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/astephenb/kh94831m/)

Answer (score 0):

In case when you set max as 1000, yAxis always will have this value on top. So better is using a [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner) and calculate ticks.